# Is mandatory explicit upcasting possible in C++

Tags: c++, casting, explicit

Suppose that `A` derives from `B`. Is there a way to forbid an implicit upcast like the one in `B *x = new A()` by making an explicit cast necessary, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to completely prevent this conversion.

You could prevent it in most places (but not in friends or members of `A`) using private inheritance, or by replacing inheritance with a containment or aggregation relation (where `A` contains an instance of or pointer/reference to `B`, rather then inheriting). Then a member function could simulate an explicit cast:

```
B * x = new A();   // not allowed
A * a = new A();   // OK
B * b = a->to_B(); // OK
```

But you should think about what behaviour you actually want to prevent, rather than making a perfectly normal operation require jumping through a rather odd hoop. There's almost certainly a better way to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. Private inheritance is not possible in my case, because the rest of the interface must be accessible. As for containment, it's a nice idea but, as you say, rather cumbersome. And just to explain myself, my intention is that the user explicitly commits to the up-cast.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible and against the rules of polymorphism.
Since A is derived from B, A is a B. So a cast is not needed, B is the mother class of A. Any instance of A can be changed to an instance of B.

That is what you want basically because it allows for programming towards interfaces.
Usually the interface, although interfaces don't exist in C++ , is defined via some kind of abstract class. The code is usually in a better shape if you are able to keep referring to the interface and keep away from the actual implementation of a certain interface.

Comment: It's not *per se* against the rules of polymorphism, I'd say. You may be right about your objections regarding interfaces. Still, imho it's a question of language definition whether it is allows to forbid implicit up-casts, and sometimes you might want to make the user commit to the up-cast.

Comment: It isn't possible to make the upcast mandatory, but it is entirely possible to prevent the implicit upcast. That's (part of) what `protected` and `private` inheritance do. Just because `std::is_base_of_v<A, B> == true` doesn't mean that `B b; A &a = b;` is valid or well-formed.

Comment: yes, you are right of course when dealing with private and protected inheritance. I forgot about those because I hardly ever use them. The way I use OOP, I am really thinging in the direction of interfaces and programming towards to most abstract thing. As such, an abstract class in C++. Moreover, C++ is a complex language, there is also virtual inheritance. I have been in situation when people are using multiple inheritance, together with normal inheritance. Quite complex. At top of the hierarchy was the same class without any virtual operations. In the end they thought they had a diamond.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a wrapper class for that, something like:

```
template<typename T>
class MyPtr
{
public:
    MyPtr(T* t) : t(t) {}

    template <typename U>
    MyPtr(U*) = delete;

    MyPtr operator = (T* t) { this->t = t; return *this; }

    template <typename U>
    MyPtr operator = (U* t) = delete;

    operator T* () const { return t; }

private:
    T* t;
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/co48in)